# How to access an object list in a private method?

Tags: c#, list, object, sharepoint

I need to acess a list of objects that in being instanced at the moment that the SharePoint Workflow is activated.

```
private void onWorkflowActivated_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
    string json = @"[
        {
            'StateID': 1,
            'Title': 'State One'
        },
        {
            'StateID': 2,
            'Title': 'State Two'
        }
    ]";

    Json j = new Json();

    List<State> states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<State>>(json);
}
```

I need to be able to access the list when I change to another step of the workflow by doing similar to the following:

```
private void StateOneTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StateOneTask_TaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
        StateOneTask_ContentTypeId = TaskContentType;
        createStateOneTask.TaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
        createStateOneTask.TaskProperties.Title = states[0].Title;
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm currently not being able to acess the list as it is in a private method. What can I do?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't make it public?

Comment: @Bas it's not about just making it public, it needs to be declared outside of this method so that it is accessible to other methods.

Comment: I'm not able to use the acess the list even if I make it public, I don't think that's problem.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn the concept of scope. C# has block-level scoping, meaning a variable declared inside {curly braces} cannot be accessed from outside those braces. If you want a variable to be accessible between different blocks, you need to declare it at a higher level (outside those {curly braces}). That's what @WasteD's solution accomplishes by moving the variable declaration outside the `onWorkflowActivated_Invoked` function.

Comment: What if I declare `public List<State> states { get; set; }` outside `onWorkflowActivated_Invoked` and then `states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<State>>(json);` inside it?

Answer (score 1):

What if you just create an instance var?

```
 class YourClass {
    private List<State> states;
    private void onWorkflowActivated_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
         string json = @"[
         {
            'StateID': 1,
            'Title': 'State One'
         },
         {
            'StateID': 2,
            'Title': 'State Two'
         }
         ]";

         Json j = new Json();

         states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<State>>(json);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your states variable is created in a stack and exists only in onWorkflowActivated_Invoked event scope. As soon as method is finished, variable does not exist anymore. As a solution I would offer you to move this variable definition out of event scope. 
You can read more about it here: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx